# Laravel do check selected items from array on html select as multiple feature

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

After get all categories and user selected categories for selected post with this result:

```
$content_categories = ContentCategories::all()->pluck('title', 'id');

Collection {#209 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => "laravel"
    2 => "nodejs"
    3 => "php"
  ]
}

$selected_categories = $manage_content->categories()->get()->pluck('title', 'id');

Collection {#223 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => "laravel"
    2 => "php"
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to implement this result on html `select` and do check selected items when we have in `$selected_categories`, this code only show `$content_categories` and can not be check items with `$selected_categories` by default

```
{{ 
  Form::select('categories[]', 
          $content_categories,
          $selected_categories, 
          array('multiple'=>'multiple'))
}}
```

result:

```
<select class="multiselect-success" multiple="multiple" name="categories[]">
     <option value="1">laravel</option>
     <option value="2">nodejs</option>
     <option value="3">php</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think because there is 'laravel' and 'php' is common in both `$content_categories` and `$selected_categories`. Try to change it other values in `$selected_categories`

Comment: OP Are you for real? Rejected my edit, then applied my edit as your own?

Comment: @ProEvilz i'm so sorry sir, because i update post after your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get IDs of selected categories without titles:

```
$selected_categories = $manage_content->categories()->pluck('id');
```

Or use `keys()` to get keys only:

```
Form::select('categories[]', $content_categories, $selected_categories->keys(), array('multiple'=>'multiple'))
```

Comment: i dont have selected items after update to your code

Comment: using `pluck('title', 'id')` and `->keys()` resolved my problem